# Wait for callback to finish on during pubnub history() call on client reconnect

Tags: javascript, callback, closures, pubnub

I have two channels for my subscribers: **Broadcast** and **Unique** channel. On the **Broadcast** channel I have all the **Subscribers** listening to. The **Unique** channel is for One-To-One communication between the **Publisher** and the **Subscriber**.

I need to achieve the following solution: If the **Subscriber** goes offline/loses connection, after he comes back online he needs to poll the two channels for the single latest message on each of them and determine if the message is still valid based on the property in the **message** object:

```
//HERE IS THE MESSAGE OBJECT THAT THE PUBLISHER SENDS ON THE BROADCAST AND THE UNIQUE
//CHANNELS TO THE SUBSCRIBERS. 
message = {
    alarm: null, //BOOLEAN: DESIGNATES IF THE ALARM IS ON/OFF
    body: null, //STRING: SOME MESSAGE/ALARM TEXT
    image: null, //STRING: SOME IMAGE IF YOU WANT TO APPEAR WITH THE ALARM TEXT
    createdAt: null, //UNIX TIMESTAMP OF WHEN THE MESSAGE WAS CREATED/SENT
    validUntil: null //UNIX TIMESTAMP - AFTER THIS PERIOD THE MESSAGE IS CONSIDERED INACTIVE AND THE SUBSCRIBER SHOULD IGNORE THIS MESSAGE ON RECONNECT
};
```

Here is my sample code for the **Subscriber**(The problem is marked in the comments in the code):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var uuid = PUBNUB.uuid(),
        id = 'vlatkorun-' + uuid,        
        controlChannel = 'vlatkorun-control',
        broadcastChannel = 'vlatkorun-broadcast',
        uniqueChannel = 'vlatkorun-unique-';

    var state = {
      id: id,
      uniqueChannel: uniqueChannel
    };

    //INIT PUBNUB
    var pubnub = PUBNUB.init({
        subscribe_key : 'YYY',
        keepalive: 30
    }); 

    //SUBSCRIBE TO THE CONTROL CHANNEL FIRST
    //THE CONTROL CHANNEL IS FOR MAINTENANCE BETWEEN PUBLISHER 
    //AND THE SUBSCRIBERS
    pubnub.subscribe ({
       channel: controlChannel,
       message: function(m){console.log(m)},
       state: state,
       heartbeat: 30,
       connect: function(m){/*console.log(JSON.stringify(m))*/},
       reconnect: function(m){console.log(JSON.stringify(m))}
    }); 

    //NOW SUBSCRIBE TO THE BROADCAST AND THE UNIQUE CHANNELS
    pubnub.subscribe ({
        channel: [broadcastChannel, uniqueChannel],
        state: state,
        message: function(data){
            //SHOW THE ALARM IN THE BROWSER WHEN MESSAGE ARRIVES
            //OUTPUT OMMITED
        },
        connect: function(m){

            //THIS ARRAY IS GOING TO HOLD THE LATEST MESSAGES FROT THE BOTH CHANNELS
            var channelLatestMessages = [];

            //GET THE MOST RECENT MESSAGE ON THE BROACAST CHANNEL
            pubnub.history({
              channel: broadcastChannel,
              count: 1,
              callback: function (m) {
                if(m[0].length > 0)
                {
                    //GO OVER THE RETURNED MESSAGES AND PUT THEM IN THE ARRAY FOR COMPARING LATER
                    $.each(m[0], function(index, value){
                        channelLatestMessages.push(value);
                    });
                }
                //I HAVE THE VARIABLE POPULATED WITH THE MESSAGES FROM THE CHANNEL IN THE CALLBACK
                console.info(channelLatestMessages);                
              },
            });

            //GET THE MOST RECENT MESSAGE ON THE UNIQUE CHANNEL
            pubnub.history({
              channel: uniqueChannel,
              count: 1,
              callback: function (m) {
                if(m[0].length > 0)
                {
                    //GO OVER THE RETURNED MESSAGES AND PUT THEM IN THE ARRAY FOR COMPARING LATER
                    $.each(m[0], function(index, value){
                        channelLatestMessages.push(value);
                    });
                }

                //I HAVE THE VARIABLE POPULATED WITH THE MESSAGES FROM THE CHANNEL IN THE CALLBACK
                console.info(channelLatestMessages);
              },
            }); 

            //I HAVE THE VARIABLE POPULATED WITH THE MESSAGES FROM THE CHANNEL IN THE CALLBACK, BUT HERE THE ARRAY IS EMPTY BECAUSE THE CALLBACKS ARENT
            //FISHED. 
            //HERE IS MY QUESTION: HOW CAN I WAIT FOR THE CALLBACKS TO FINISH SO I CAN CONTINUE WITH MY CODE BELLOW???
            console.info(channelLatestMessages);            

            //IF THERE ARE NO MESSAGES DO NOTHING
            if(channelLatestMessages.length == 0) return;   

            //ASSUME THAT THE FIRST MESSAGE IN THE ARRAY IS THE MOST RECENT
            latestMessage = channelLatestMessages[0];

            //NOW FIGURE OUT THE MOST RECENT MESSAGE
            $.each(channelLatestMessages, function(index, message){
                if(latestMessage.createdAt < message.createdAt)
                {
                    latestMessage = message;                    
                }
            });         

            //GET THE CURRENT DATE IN UNIX TIMESTAMP
            var currentDate = parseInt(moment().format('X'));
            //CHECK IF THE MESSAGE VALIDITY IS EXPIRED
            if(currentDate > latestMessage.validUntil) return;          

            //HERE WE CAN SHOW THE LATEST MESSAGE IN THE BROWSER
            //OUTPUT OMMITED
        },
        reconnect: function(m){//THE SAME LOGIN LIKE IN THE CONNECT METHOD APPLIES HERE}
    });         
});
```

How to wait for the callbacks to finish so I can have the **channelLatestMessages** filled with the latest messages from the **Broadcast** and **Unique** channels so I can further determine which message is more recent and if the more recent message is still active?

Answer (score 0):

Can your logic run like this:

historyCall-1's callback calls historyCall-2.
historyCall-2's callback calls "Message Age Detection" logic.

This way, we make the async act synchronously, and the only way "Message Age Detection" logic runs is if we know for a fact that history calls 1 and 2 are complete.

?

geremy